# Implementing Callback Interface using 2 generic parameters in Java 6

Tags: java, function, generics, interface, callback

```
// interface
public interface Callback<T, R> {
    R execute(T arg);
}

// application code
logger = MetricLogger.getInstance(app);

logger.write(new Callback<LogFormat, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void execute(LogFormat arg) {
        // do something
        return null;
    }
 });
```

When I return `Void` type, above code compiles and works.

But I can't use `Long` as the return type. For example

```
logger = MetricLogger.getInstance(app);

// doesn't compile
logger.write(new Callback<LogFormat, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long execute(LogFormat arg) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

The error message is,

> Error:(66, 22) error: incompatible types: anonymous `Callback 
>   <LogFormat,Long>` cannot be converted to `Callback<LogFormat,Void>`

Java 6 doesn't support the generic return type?
Or am I missing something?

=================================================================

Updated

I found these code *compile*. But I can't sure which one is correct

```
// Solution 1
public interface Callback<T> {
  <R> R execute(T arg)
}

new Callback<LogFormat>() {
  @Override
  public Long execute(LogFormat arg) { ... }
}

// Solution 2
public interface Callback {
  <T, R> R execute(T arg)
}

new Callback<LogFormat>() {
  @Override
  public <LogFormat, Long> Long execute(LogFormat arg) { ... }
}
```

Comment: The logger.write() method seems only to accept Callback<LogFormat,Void>. Also the provided code seems not to match the provided Error: Callback<RakeClientMetricSentinelShuttle, Long> VS Callback<LogFormat, Long>

Comment: @Mikey, did you compile the code?

Comment: No - I don't know where MetricLogger is coming from: see Prims answer

Comment: I think Prims answer is right: the right Solution depends on usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The write method on Logger class has probably a signature like :
`void write(Callback<? extends Object, Void> callback)` which doesn't let you pass other than Void type

If it's your logger class implementation,you can change the signature, it should be something like 
`void write(Callback<? extends Object, ? extends Object> callback)` to let you use any type